# Xamarin camera2 api is in background not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-camera2

I am interested in Xamarin and I search, how I can take a photo from camera without device's native camera application. And I found Camera2 API, then I search sample app and I found this sample app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android50-camera2basic/

It worked very well when I tried it in the foreground but it gives an error when I put it in the background.

How can I get it running in the background?

Camera2BasicFragment.cs codes: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CqDkyMx8qW/

Exceptions:

[Exception image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRzZG.png)

[Exception image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5z6k.png)

Exception Text:

```
{Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallIntMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <dac4c5a4b77f4e61a5e6d9d3050dfb9f>:0   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractInt32Method (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <dac4c5a4b77f4e61a5e6d9d3050dfb9f>:0   at Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraCaptureSessionInvoker.Capture (Android.Hardware.Camera2.CaptureRequest request, Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraCaptureSession+CaptureCallback listener, Android.OS.Handler handler) [0x0006e] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/204/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-27/mcw/Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraCaptureSession.cs:969   at Camera2Basic.Camera2BasicFragment.LockFocus () [0x00020] in C:\Users\Harun\Desktop\x\Camera2Basic\Camera2BasicFragment.cs:576   at Camera2Basic.Camera2BasicFragment.TakePicture () [0x00001] in C:\Users\Harun\Desktop\x\Camera2Basic\Camera2BasicFragment.cs:563   at Camera2Basic.Camera2BasicFragment.OnClick (Android.Views.View v) [0x00013] in C:\Users\Harun\Desktop\x\Camera2Basic\Camera2BasicFragment.cs:676   at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_v) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/204/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-27/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:2176   at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.19(intptr,intptr,intptr)  --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace ---java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1997)  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:844)   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.capture(CameraDeviceImpl.java:741)    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.capture(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:179)    at crc64b678081366886b9e.Camera2BasicFragment.n_onClick(Native Method)  at crc64b678081366886b9e.Camera2BasicFragment.onClick(Camera2BasicFragment.java:77) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10936)    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)}
```

Comment: You will need to perform your camera processing via the Camera2 API in a Foreground Service, from there you can display the frames in an Activity/Fragment if needed via binding to the service (i.e. a Bounded (Foreground) Service)

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks, I will try

Comment: @SushiHangover I found a open source project on GitHub. This project take a picture in background very well silently with Camera2 API. https://github.com/Leonov-Artem/Task2/   This project is creating foreground service and we can take picture very well :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post relevant code in your question and don't link to an off-site resource with the code. Also, please narrow the code down to where the issue is. If you have found the solution to your question, please also post it here as an answer for people which may encounter the same issue.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thanks, I will pay attention to the rules.